# Accessing template reference variable from sibling element event within *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a template reference variable `#profiletextedit` on a textarea element, within an `*ngFor`.

I also have a `(keydown.enter)` event that successfully passes the variable to an event handler in my component.

I also have a `(click)` event on a button that fails to pass the same variable to the same event handler. It returns `undefined`.

Can anybody help me understand why?

```
<div *ngFor="let profile of profiles" class="selectable card-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <p *ngIf="!profile.isEditMode">{{profile.text}}</p>
            <textarea *ngIf="profile.isEditMode" class="form-control" #profiletextedit (keydown.enter)="updateProfileText(profiletextedit, profile);false" rows="5">{{profile.text}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <div class="float-xs-right">
                <button *ngIf="profile.isEditMode" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="updateProfileText(profiletextedit, profile);">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a known bug, related to using a template reference variable on a `*ngIf` conditioned element. Take a look at the github issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6179

Therefore, in your case, if you remove `*ngIf="profile.isEditMode"`, it will work as expected. You'll find other workarounds in the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure. It should work as expected - look here  
https://plnkr.co/edit/6JXdzTgW3tCaH0baaMO4?p=preview.

Try to use **`profiletextedit.value`** as shown below,

```
<div class="float-xs-right">
                <button *ngIf="profile.isEditMode" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" 
                         (click)="updateProfileText(profiletextedit.value, profile);">
                          Add
                </button>
 </div>
```